# Csrf token not being rendered in the UI for a simple Html form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

I am trying to implement the Csrf protection for a simple registration application. I have a state changing form registration.jsp which needs to protected with csrf token validation. I have imported spring security 5.2.3 dependencies and also added the hidden input tag in registration.jsp. From the spring csrf documentation it is evident that  we should be able to see the token set in header or cookie value.

```
<form:label path="note">Note:</form:label>
            <form:textarea path="note" cols="25" rows="5"/><br/>
            <form:button>Register</form:button>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />    
        </form:form>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default form method is `GET`, which does not require a CSRF-token. Setting the form method to `POST` should add a CSRF-token if it is not disabled as described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure):

You should be able to see the csrf-token in the payload of the `POST`-request with the key `_csrf` in the network tab of the Chrome debugger.

It seems to be [by design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) that the hidden input field is not rendered.

> Hidden inputs are completely invisible in the rendered page, and there is no way to make it visible in the page's content.

Otherwise, what you have done should be the equivalent of using the csrftag `<sec:csrfInput />` from the [Spring Security JSP tag library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#the-csrfinput-tag).